# SQL Developer auto trace does not show cascading deletes

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

I'm trying to understand the performance characteristics of SQL statement that does DELETE cascade on 4 linked tables.

When I do the auto tracing of the statement it only shows me the DELETE statement executed on the table. It does not show details of deletes done on other tables.

Why doesn't SQL Developer show cascades in tracing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autotrace in SQL Developer gets you the v$sql_plan of your query and the session stats accumulated during the execution of your query - it does not show any recursive SQL that may get executed.

To see that you'd actually want to trace your session.